# Feature to Line on feature selections with ArcPy

Tags: arcmap, arcpy

I'm trying to collapse parallel polylines (dual carriageways in a shapefile of roads) to single centrelines.  I'm aware of [cartography's dual lines to centerline tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001300000042000000), but I find [Feature To Line (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000039000000) slightly more reliable.  The challenge is that whichever function is used requires a large tolerance (e.g. 10m+) so must be applied to custom selections of data in order to avoid creating new artifacts between unrelated pairs - hence the need for custom selections, which as far as I can tell these functions can't handle.

I'm pretty new to ArcPy so advice on creating temporary layers to work with would be very helpful.  As a starting point just assume a polylines shapefile.  The planned workflow is to rejoin these with the other road data once they've been collapsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution (based on advice from [ArcGIS Forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/85282-Feature-to-Line-on-feature-selections-with-ArcPy)), but it works for me:

```
fieldNames = getValueList("shapefile", "FIELD")
fieldNames = map(str, fieldNames)

# blank layer for results called 'merged'
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("C:\\PATH", "merged.shp", "POLYLINE", "shapefile.shp", "SAME_AS_TEMPLATE", "SAME_AS_TEMPLATE", "shapefile.shp")

for each in fieldNames:
    defQuery = "\"FIELD\" = '%s'" % (each)
    # create temporary layer of DCs with same official road identifier
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("shapefile", "selectn", defQuery)
    # run centre-line function on the selection and assign to new layer
    arcpy.FeatureToLine_management("selectn", "newSelectn", "20.0 Meters", "ATTRIBUTES")
    arcpy.Append_management("newSelectn", "merged", "NO_TEST")
    arcpy.Delete_management("newSelectn.shp")
    arcpy.Delete_management('selectn')
```